# How to make php-textile Open Link in a _blank target

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am using txstyle.org text syntax for user styled documents.

When I try to render them using php-textile

```
use Netcarver\Textile\Parser as Textile;
$parser = new Textile();
echo $parser->textileThis($textToBeFormatted);
```

They work pretty well, but I could not find a way to set target="_blank" on the links parsed.

How to set targets for selective links? if not, at least for all links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two approaches to solve this.

```
$parser->textileThis($textToBeFormatted);
```

Took the output and appended it to a PHP DOM object and with help of XPath I have parsed every  anchor tag to add an attribute target="_blank".

The second approach is with jQuery on the client side to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control the input use standard HTML

```
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.com" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
```

Otherwise I'd approach it from a simmilar way to sujaisd suggested.
If you're feeling adventurous you could always modify/extend your version of php textile to support a syntax for targets.